# Bootstrap-Heading in mobile device width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I have a problem with Bootstrap. I have an `h2`-Heading and on mobile screens it goes out of range. I cant post an image-example, because I'm a newbie.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
<header id="header" role="banner">
...
</header>
<section id="section1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box box-one">
            <div class="center gap">
                <h2>Sadipscing  Takimata sanctus est</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  padding: 50px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
}

#section1 .box-one {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.gap {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

What cause this experience?

Regards

Comment: You need to be way more specific, come with code examples and screenshots. We are not going to shoot in the dark ! apart from that I don't see any bootstrap elements being used in your snippet yet.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I use Bootstrap-min v3.0.0!

Comment: You're definitely not setting width anywhere?

Comment: show the css properties of all the `class` and `id` in the `<section>` tag

Comment: @John perhaps provide more html. It may be a malformed document.

Answer (score 1):

```
<section class="container" id="section1">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-one">
                <div class="center gap">
                    <h2>Sadipscing  Takimata sanctus est</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am assuming that you are using the heading for full width if not then change the `col-md-12` to `col-md-11` or just decrease that number further play around with it

**CSS**

```
.box {
padding: auto;
background: #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
position: relative;
}

#section1 .box-one {
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.gap {
margin-bottom: auto;
}
@media all and (mix-width: 699px)
        {
            .box{padding: 50px 30px;}
            .gap {margin-bottom: 40px;}
        }
```

Comment: Probably the answer but may need to have `col-md-12` as it's own div since it could fight with .box or .box-one in weird ways.

Comment: @JeremyCook you maybe right as we don't know the style properties of `.box` and `.box-one`

Comment: No effect! Still the same problem. Also with using a row-div.

    <section id="section1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="box box-one">
            <div class="col-md-12 center gap">
              <h2>Sadipscing  Takimata sanctus est</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

Comment: I suggest updating your response and wrapping it in a `.row` div. I am feeling like earlier versions of bootstrap were OK without .row but now .row is required. (I think)

Comment: @John It could be your text is too long and text is told not to wrap.

Comment: Looks good in this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2BQpc/2/. It's too bad @John cannot provide a screenshot

Comment: @John its your `.box` padding thats creating the problem

Comment: I found a bad CSS: .box h2 {padding: 10px 30px; display: inline-block; border-radius: 4px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 30px; font-size: 48px; color: #fff;
} I delete it, and now it looks good. But i dont understand this: Now my header on Desktop is too small with h2. Changing it to h1, i get same look :( h2 looks good on mobile, but on dektop is to small. How to handle it?

Comment: What i need is something like responsive font size. Showing here: http://www.screenlight.tv/ Is this already a feature in Bootstrap?

Comment: @John You do not need that unless you have defined a font size in you style. The website you pointed out is using bootstrap i guess, as the class names are the same as bootstrap. If you still want a responsive font size just add h1{font-size:thesizeyouwant}